# Explain AWS API Gateway Rest API for publishing documentation

Tags: amazon-web-services

AWS Documentation has snippets of code all over the place that look like this:

```
POST /restapis/restapi_id/documentation/versions HTTP/1.1
Host: apigateway.region.amazonaws.com
Content-Type: application/json
X-Amz-Date: YYYYMMDDTttttttZ
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=access_key_id/YYYYMMDD/region/apigateway/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=sigv4_secret

{
    "documentationVersion" : "1.0.0",
    "stageName": "prod",
    "description" : "My API Documentation v1.0.0"
}
```

Source: [Publish API documentation using the API Gateway REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-documenting-api-quick-start-publishing.html)

What am I supposed to do with this? Does AWS have instructions explaining how to read their API calls? I like to use cURL. Is there a good way to translate these calls into something curl can use?

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing on the AWS documentation page is a plain HTTP stream. It's the least common denominator for every technology that is able to talk HTTP, not making any assumptions about the tools or libraries.

Technically, you can connect to the AWS endpoint using `openssl s_client apigateway.region.amazonaws.com:443` and just paste this request to the command's stdin. But it's not a convenient way to do that.

This page assumes you are familiar enough with HTTP to be able translate it to your particular tool or library.

[Curl manual page](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html) would be a good start on learning how to run this request with cUrl.

In particular:

```bash
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Amz-Date: YYYYMMDDTttttttZ" \
-H "Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=access_key_id/YYYYMMDD/region/apigateway/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=sigv4_secret" \
-d '{"documentationVersion":"1.0.0","stageName":"prod","description":"My API Documentation v1.0.0"}' \
https://apigateway.region.amazonaws.com/restapis/"$RESTAPI_ID"/documentation/versions
```

(assuming you run it from bash).

You'll need to provide valid authorization to run this request. It means that you will have to replace `sigv4_secret` in the Authorization header with an actual signature. Curl can fill out the `Authorization` header for you if you provide it with the parameter `--aws-sigv4` and your credentials in `--user`

AWS also provides [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html), which is a wrapper around these requests. It will handle authorization and JSON composition for you. Invoking this request using CLI would look something [like this](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/apigateway/create-documentation-version.html):

```bash
aws apigateway create-documentation-version \
  --rest-api-id="$RESTAPI_ID" \
  --documentation-version="1.0.0" \
  --stage-name="prod" \
  --description="My API Documentation v1.0.0"
```